# Footer, make 2 contact paragraphs same line, have spacing between the two contact info

Tags: html, css, spacing

friendly web users, this problem really got me stuck.

HTML code:

```css
       
#footer {
   position: absolute;
   left: 500px;
   bottom: 0px;
    }
    
  .contact_footer{
   float: left;
   display: inline;
    }
```

```html
<footer>
 
  <div id="footer">
   <div class="contact_footer">
   <h3>Contact</h3>
   <address>
   **Address information**
   </address>
   </div>
 
  <div class="contact_footer">
   <h3>Factory</h3>
   <address> 
   2nd Address information
   </address>
  </div>
  </div>
 </footer>
```

As you can see, I am trying to create a **footer** with **2** different pieces of contact information **side by side** with at least 50 pixels of **spacing** between them. I was able to place them side by side with the

```
 display: inline
```

code, but I was unable to have a space between them, what is the bug here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple example using using flexbox. Flexbox can be use to create "constraints" like this where behaviour is more important than size.

```css
.footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
  <ul class="footer__list">
    <li class="footer__list-item">List 1</li>
    <li class="footer__list-item">List 1</li>
    <li class="footer__list-item">List 1</li>
    <li class="footer__list-item">List 1</li>
    <li class="footer__list-item">List 1</li>
  </ul>
  
  <ul class="footer__list">
    <li class="footer__list-item">List 2</li>
    <li class="footer__list-item">List 2</li>
    <li class="footer__list-item">List 2</li>
    <li class="footer__list-item">List 2</li>
    <li class="footer__list-item">List 2</li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a flexbox and define for space to be in between. Setting the left margin for `.contact_footer` will guarantee the minimum space between the elements.

Padding and margin for inline elements [can sometimes seem a bit unpredictable](http://maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/). Alternatively, you can set the display to `inline-block`.
Avoiding floats will keep all your elements in the normal document flow.

```css
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 500px;
  bottom: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.contact_footer {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div id="footer">
    <div class="contact_footer">
      <h3>Contact</h3>
      <address>
   **Address information**
   </address>
    </div>

    <div class="contact_footer">
      <h3>Factory</h3>
      <address> 
   2nd Address information
   </address>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding margin-left or margin-right in the contact_footer class